# Incomplete sphere OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry, draw, vbo

I want to draw a sphere using VBO for vertex, color and UV coordinates for texture. My problem is that the sphere is not 'closed', there is a hole in the origin. I know that this is because my code depends on (1/segments) distance between each vertex; I am working with segments = 40.
I know that, if I rise that value, the hole will be lower, but program is slower. I don't know if there's a way to eliminate the hole without rise the variable.

Here's the code:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= segments; i++){

    double lat0 = pi * (-0.5 + (double)(i - 1) / segments);
    double z0 = sin(lat0);
    double zr0 = cos(lat0);
    // lat1 = [-pi/2..pi/2]
    double lat1 = pi * (-0.5 + (double)i / segments);
    double z1 = sin(lat1);
    double zr1 = cos(lat1);

    for (int j = 0; j <= segments; j++){    // Longitud
        // lng = [0..2*pi]
        double lng = 2 * pi * (double)(j - 1) / segments;
        double x = cos(lng);
        double y = sin(lng);
        //glNormal3f(x * zr0, y * zr0, z0); // Normals
        ballVerts.push_back(x * zr0); //X
        ballVerts.push_back(y * zr0); //Y
        ballVerts.push_back(z0);      //Z

        ballVerts.push_back(0.0f);
        ballVerts.push_back(0.0f);
        ballVerts.push_back(0.0f);
        ballVerts.push_back(1.0f); //R,G,B,A

        texX = abs(1 - (0.5f + atan2(z0, x * zr0) / (2.0 * pi)));
        texY = 0.5f - asin(y * zr0) / pi;
        ballVerts.push_back(texX);  // Texture coords
        ballVerts.push_back(texY);  // U, V


        //glNormal3f(x * zr1, y * zr1, z1); //Normals
        ballVerts.push_back(x * zr1); //X
        ballVerts.push_back(y * zr1); //Y
        ballVerts.push_back(z1);      //Z
        ballVerts.push_back(0.0f);
        ballVerts.push_back(0.0f);
        ballVerts.push_back(1.0f);
        ballVerts.push_back(1.0f); //R,G,B,A

        texX = abs(1 - (0.5f + atan2(z1, x * zr1) / (2.0 * pi)));
        texY = 0.5f - asin(y * zr1) / pi;
        ballVerts.push_back(texX);  // Texture coords
        ballVerts.push_back(texY);

    }
}
// Create VBO....
```

And this is the output I have:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's a hole. You're drawing one segment too many, and causing it to draw additional triangles at the south pole, with the texture wrapped around:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= segments; i++){
    double lat0 = pi * (-0.5 + (double)(i - 1) / segments);
```

In the first loop iteration, with `i = 0`, the angle will be less than `-0.5 * pi`, resulting in the extra triangles shown in your picture.

If you want to split the latitude range into `segments` pieces, you only need to run through the outer loop `segments` times. With the code above, with the loop from `0` up to and including `segments`, you're iterating `segments + 1` times.

The easiest way to fix this is to start the loop at `1`:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= segments; i++){
    double lat0 = pi * (-0.5 + (double)(i - 1) / segments);
```

I would probably loop from 0 and make the end exclusive, and change the angle calculations. But that's really equivalent:

```
for(int i = 0; i < segments; i++){
    double lat0 = pi * (-0.5 + (double) / segments);
    ...
    double lat1 = pi * (-0.5 + (double)(i + 1) / segments);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was extremely easy to understand! Now I see it.